# pycharm convert tabs to spaces automatically

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using pycharm IDE for python development it works perfectly fine for django code so suspected that converting tabs to spaces is default behaviour, however in python IDE is giving errors everywhere because it can't convert tabs to spaces automatically is there a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Change the code style to use spaces instead of tabs:

[image: spaces]

Then select a folder you want to convert in the Project View and use `Code` | **Reformat Code**.

Comment: this was my default setting however it seems like there was some bug in the IDE which was not working so what I did is Edit>Convert Indent>Spaces

Comment: Python should have 4-space indentation.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me. Not sure why it's accepted, seeing as it doesn't work for OP either. Follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47102828/is-it-possible-in-pycharm-to-map-a-tab-to-produce-4-spaces-if-so-how

Comment: In my case I had to disable Editor Config under Editor -> Code Style -> Enable Editor Config Support, because I unknowingly had a `~/.editorconfig` file overriding PyCharm's settings.

Comment: This sets the default. It does NOT alter tabs or spaces in an existing file. See the answer below from @LowKianSeong for a solution that addresses the question.

Comment: You can force it to use spaces even for existing files by unchecking "Detect and use existing file indents for editing" under the general "Code Style". After that, typing tab on an existing file will immediately insert spaces rather than tabs.

Comment: I had to check and uncheck the checkbox to make it work.

Answer (score 92):

This only converts the tabs without changing anything else:

```
Edit -> Convert Indents -> To Spaces
```

Comment: Hey, this should be the accepted. It works locally. E.g. useful for Makefile that need to have tab as indentation

Answer (score 63):

For selections, you can also convert the selection using the "To spaces" function. I usually just use it via the ctrl-shift-A then find "To Spaces" from there.

Comment: doesn't seem to work for multiple files at once. doing it for each file individually is kind of a hassle...

Comment: you sir, are a life savor

Answer (score 32):

## PyCharm 2019.1

### If you want to change the general settings:

Open preferences, in macOS <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> or in Windows/Linux <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

Go to Editor -> Code Style -> Python, and if you want to follow PEP-8, choose *Tab size: 4*, *Indent: 4*, and *Continuation indent: 8* as shown below:

[image]

Apply the changes, and click on OK.

### If you want to apply the changes just to the current file

**Option 1:** You can choose in the navigation bar: Edit -> Convert Indent -> To Spaces. (see image below)

[image]

**Option 2:** You can execute "To Spaces" action by running the *Find Action* shortcut: <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> on macOS or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> on Windows/Linux. Then type "To Spaces", and run the action as shown in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

**ctrl + shift + A** => open pop window to select options, select **to spaces** to convert all tabs as space, or **to tab** to convert all spaces as tab.

Comment: This only works for indents, not general formatting

Answer (score 7):

ctr+alt+shift+L ->  reformat whole file :)

Comment: to tabs didn't work to convert an existing block of code. This is the only solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me it was having a file called ~/.editorconfig that was overriding my tab settings. I removed that (surely that will bite me again someday) but it fixed my pycharm issue

Answer (score 1):

Just ot note: Pycharm's ***to spaces*** function only works on indent tabs at the *beginning* of a line, not interstitial tabs *within* a line of text. for example, when you are trying to format columns in monospaced text.