# how can i configure python IDLE, so that it shows color in each indentation?

Tags: python, python-idle

lack of indentation color, occurs problem where the indentation is missing. is there anyone who can help me to configure IDLE to show color (light\dim color) in each indentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to 'see' / highlight tabs and spaces in PyCharm for checking indentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45112625/how-to-see-highlight-tabs-and-spaces-in-pycharm-for-checking-indentation)

Comment: @GáborPálovics This question is not about Pycharm...

Comment: @GáborPálovics no. I am asking about python IDLE

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for or why (what problem are you trying to solve).  By default, IDLE will not let you put tab indents into an editor.  Rather, it converts tabs before text to spaces.  Starting in 3.10.0b1, the same is true in IDLE's Shell also.  If the issue is counting the number of spaces, coloring them or replacing them with another symbol will not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**'Show color in each indentation?"**

In my Python 3.7 IDLE, I managed to distinguish the multiple levels of indentation in iterations (by default, the IDLE would show orange color for starting code text). It seems that we only able to adjust the indentation space (default is 4 spaces for python) and the color of entire coding text.

We can adjust the properties in Python shell --> Options --> Configure IDLE.