# Can I automatically format files to use spaces instead of tabs in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

If I open an existing project into PyCharm that used tabs instead of spaces can I format all of these files within PyCharm or do I need to manually update all of them?

Comment: I can't flag this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816147/pycharm-convert-tabs-to-spaces-automatically because I still don't have the reputation but I believe this is what you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, assuming you have PyCharm set to automatically produce spaces instead of tabs (which is default, as far as I know).

In the menu:

`Code -> Reformat Code` with the top-level folder selected.

Answer (score 0):

Just treat it like a text file and replace the tabs:

```
with open('example.py') as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()

lines = [line.replace('\t', '    ') for line in lines]

with open('example.py', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: Edit -> Convert Indents -> To Spaces

There are also some quick ways to do this from a UNIX shell.