# Is it possible in Pycharm to map a tab to produce 4 spaces. If so how?

Tags: pycharm, keymapping

this is my first time using an IDE.  I was wondering if its possible, as I've done in vim with imap, to make it so that when I press tab 4 spaces are produced in the editor.  If this is possible, please point me how to do it.  I'm not super familiar with key symbols so please be as explicit a possible; I poked around the keymap under settings but it was pretty confusing.

Comment: in my case I had to disable Editor Config under Editor -> Code Style -> Enable Editor Config Support, because I unknowingly had a ~/.editorconfig file overriding PyCharm's settings

Comment: Else, I think answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816147/pycharm-convert-tabs-to-spaces-automatically should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the Tab size in Pycharm. Goto Preference --> Editor --> Code Style --> Python.

Comment: It was set to 4 however in my case it puts 3 spaces. If I leave it like that it warns me that it should be 4 spaces.